# Is there an equivalent of MVVM (Model-view-viewmodel) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an equivalent of MVVM (Model-view-viewmodel) in Rails? Or possibly a library that helps this type of architecture come together.  I don't like performing too much logic in my views.

Comment: Several, although their need is reduced by view helpers or using a non-ERb view renderer. Draper is one of the older ones. It's also quite easy to roll your own.

Comment: Using HAML or Slim doesn't mean that your views will be less messy - its just a bit less noise to look at.